# Форма поиска в базе

Tags: python, django

Есть сайтик на джанго с базой sqlite и есть отдельная база sql с которой надо сделать поиск на этом сайтике, чтот не получается ее прикрутить в модельках, там создается новая или получается поиск по существующей.

Как это сделать и в каком месте документации читать =)

http://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/db/queries.html

гм, изменю вопрос, при выполнении migrate

нет модуля MySQLdb

как его поставить на вин7 х64 ? =) pip выпадает с ошибкой

Comment: http://djbook.ru/rel1.6/topics/db/multi-db.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужная документация по использованию и работе с несколькими БД и Джанго  живёт тут: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/

Бинарник MySQLdb можно найти на https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5

А вот вопросы на английском Стековерфлоу, связанные с проблемой при установке этой либы на Виндоуз: [Python: How to install mysqldb on windows 7 x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284186/python-how-to-install-mysqldb-on-windows-7-x64), [Install mysql-python (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440230/install-mysql-python-windows).